# Magento - Banners, Widgets and Static Blocks

Tags: magento, widget, banner

I'm new to Magento and I'd like to ask how can I display a banner in CMS pages?
I tried to create a new banner with some simple characters as the content and linked it to a new widget. However, the banner was not displayed on the specified page I selected. 
Besides, when I pressed the "Insert Widget..." button for a static block and selected "Banner Rotator", it is strange that the options displayed below the screen were banners, instead of widgets. Anyway I selected the banner I just created, but it could not be shown as well.

Please help, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

In order to show a banner on a cms page, you can create a static block with required HTML.

add it to the layout page for ex in : `app\design\frontend\default\newcode\layout\local.xml`

add following code in the above created file :

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
<cms_index_index>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="cms/block" name="custom.blockid">
            <action method="setBlockId">
                <block_id>custom_blockid</block_id>
            </action>
        </block>
    </reference>
</cms_index_index>
</layout>
```

Assuming that id of your static block is `custom_blockid`

Read more at http://www.magentocommerce.com/blog/comments/introducing-magento-widgets/

Comment: The banner will be displayed automatically after adding the code to the xml file? I would like to know how the banner is linked with the static block?

Comment: yes i have just checked this on my local installation.. use following steps create a static block with identifier as custom_blockid, locate or create a local.xml in your themes layout folder. add code above and this will start to show on your homepage.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to “CMS > Pages > Manage Content”
2. Select the new page
3. Go to Content
4. Press Insert Widget
5. Select Banner Rotator
6. Select the banner I just created

Hope that this helps you as I guide to achieving what you want.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but it doesn't work...the banner could not be displayed.

Comment: Have you got the correct extensions or you could use this http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/simple-banners.html